# FTP Server integration with LDAP

Tags: openldap, vsftpd

I'm trying to authenticate vsftpd from LDAP(openldap) logins which hosted remotely another server.

i.e.: We have a LDAP server and new users are created on them. I'd like to know if it is possible to use the same ldap users credential to authenticate and log in into the FTP server as I am unable to do that.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have a scenario slightly different, but probably can work in you case.

In my case, we have a Windows Domain and we use SSSD to authenticate in the domain. There is no need any change in vsftpd.

My guess is if you set up the sssd authenticating to your LDAP server, it will work.

There is a tutorial here for Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ldap